# How to Query Last 90 Days in Hana SQL (Subtract from Current Date)

Tags: sql, date, hana, date-arithmetic

I have the following query:

```
SELECT "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."SYS_ID","SURF_RT"."U_EMPLOYEE"."DV_U_EMPLOYEE_MANAGER", "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."DV_PRIMARY_SALES_REP","SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."NUMBER","SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT",
          "SALES_REQUEST"."DV_STATE","OPENED_AT","U_ANALYZED_DATE", "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV",  MAX("END_DATE") AS "ContractEnd"
FROM "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"
JOIN "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT" ON "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."NAME"="SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
JOIN "SURF_RT"."U_EMPLOYEE" ON "SURF_RT"."U_EMPLOYEE"."NAME"="SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."DV_PRIMARY_SALES_REP"
left join "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT"  on "SURF_RT"."SALES_CONTRACT"."DV_ACCOUNT"="SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT"
WHERE "DV_SALES_SUBCATEGORY" = 'Reporting Request'
AND "OPENED_AT" >= CURRENT_DATE-90
GROUP BY "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."SYS_ID","SURF_RT"."U_EMPLOYEE"."DV_U_EMPLOYEE_MANAGER", "SURF_RT"."SALES_ACCOUNT"."DV_PRIMARY_SALES_REP","SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."NUMBER","SALES_REQUEST"."DV_SALES_ACCOUNT",
          "SALES_REQUEST"."DV_STATE","OPENED_AT","U_ANALYZED_DATE", "U_USD_TOTAL_POTENTIAL_NNACV"
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Could not execute 'SELECT "SURF_RT"."SALES_REQUEST"."SYS_ID","SURF_RT"."U_EMPLOYEE"."DV_U_EMPLOYEE_MANAGER", ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [266]: inconsistent datatype: the expression has incomputable datatype: DATE is invalid for subtraction operator: line 11 col 33 (at pos 1014)
```

How can I subtract from a date in Hana SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [add_days()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.02/en-US/20da5fa8751910148969da2572b25ed8.html):

```
"OPENED_AT" >= add_days(CURRENT_DATE, -90)
```